# Javascript: How to add comma in between two object in string object but not last object

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, object

I have string object but and stored in variable pass from another class. How can I add comma in between two object but not last object. The following below is my code.

```
{
        "id":"57e4d12e53a5a",
        "body":"asdas",
        "published":"Fri, 
        23 Sep 2016 06:52:30 +0000",
        "type":"chat-message",
        "actor":
            {
            "displayName":"beau",
            "objectType":"person",
            "image":
                {
                "url":"http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/205e460b479e2e5b48aec07710c08d50?s=80&d=mm&r=g",
                "width":48,"height":48
                }
            }
    }
    {
        "id":"57e4d51165d97",
        "body":"jackiechanSADAS",
        "published":"Fri, 23 Sep 2016 07:09:05 +0000",
        "type":"chat-message",
        "actor":
            {
                "displayName":"beau",
                "objectType":"person",
                "image":
                    {
                        "url":"http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/205e460b479e2e5b48aec07710c08d50?s=80&d=mm&r=g",
                        "width":48,
                        "height":48
                    }
            }
    }
    {
        "id":"asas",
        "body":"peterting",
        "published":"Fri, 23 Sep 2016 07:09:05 +0000",
        "type":"chat-message",
        "actor":
            {
                "displayName":"beau",
                "objectType":"person",
                "image":
                    {
                        "url":"http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/205e460b479e2e5b48aec07710c08d50?s=80&d=mm&r=g",
                        "width":48,
                        "height":48
                    }
            }
    }
```

How can I add comma "," in between of object but not last object by using programming because the whole thing I store it as string and without "," I can't parse it to object.

Comment: Why not just edit the string to valid JSON instead

Comment: Try `String.replace('}{' , '},{');`

Comment: @Pugazh your code will not work because there are spaces and newlines between `}` and `{`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Regex for this:

```
JSON.parse('[' + string.replace(/}\s*{/g, '},{') + ']');
```

Comment: Solved it. Thanks